# Why is my rounded corner is not working in IE if i am using the following code

Tags: html, css

My rounded corner code is not working in IE. I have used following code for getting rounded corners. I tested in Mozilla Firefox, Chrome, and IE. But this code is not working in IE.

```
.roundedCorner{
    -moz-border-radius:22px;
    -webkit-border-radius:22px;
    -khtml-border-radius:22px;
    border-radius:22px;  
    border: 1px solid #4B8FD3;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think rounded corners would be an urgent thing.

Comment: @BoltClock They need to be round before they poke someone's eye out.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your border-radius.htc is, but that url has to be relative to the page being accessed, not the CSS file.

Also, you could take a look at [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/). It replicates most of the CSS3 features into IE and works very well, using a `.htc` file in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

< IE9 doesn't support `border-radius`. Use images, or one of the JavaScript solutions.

[CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [Curvycorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) for Crossbrowser Compatibility. It´s a great plugin